# Using Foundation icons in LaTeX document

Tags: package-writing, svg, fontawesome

I have the [`fontawesome`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) package in mind when asking this question? In fontawesome you can invoke the given symbol by typing its code to get it in the document. For example,
`\faCircleArrowDown` gives the corresponding symbol from the list.

Foundation has some basic svg icons which can be found at

http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3

Is there anyway we can invoke these icons in LaTeX document by using similar commands?

For example, `\fi-photo` should give us the corresponding icon from the list.

How can one go about writing a package which does this?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to use these icons with `lua/xelatex` and `fontspec`. Note they exist as a True Type font, with family name `fontcustom`, and font file `foundation-icons.ttf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\FI{fontcustom}%[
\def\fiPhoto{\FI{\symbol{"F195}}}
\def\fiFolder{\FI{\symbol{"F150}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\Huge}c}
\verb|\fiPhoto:| & \color{SeaGreen4}\fiPhoto \\[2ex]
\verb|\fiFolder:| & \color{VioletRed3}\fiFolder
\end{tabular}

  \end{document}
```

[image]